# Issue with custom filters in SpringSecurityFilterChain

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

I have a problem adding multiple custom filters into SpringSecurityFilterChain using Java configuration. I didn't have the problem when xml configuration was used.

I have several custom filters in and want to add them in SpringSecurityFilterChain in specific order. I define filters using @Bean method level annotation and override method for http security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public static class CustomSecurityConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
...

    @Bean
    public Filter filter1() {
        return new Filter1();
    }
    @Bean
    public Filter filter2() {
        return new Filter2();
    }
    @Bean
    public Filter filter3() {
        return new Filter3();
    }
    @Bean
    public Filter filter4() {
        return new Filter4();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...
        http.addFilterBefore(filter1(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class) 
            .addFilterBefore(filter2(), HeaderWriterFilter.class) 
            .addFilterBefore(filter3(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class) 
            .addFilterAfter(filter4(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);
        ...
    }
...
}
```

When request comes, SpringSecurityFilter chain has my custom filters, but they are all positioned one after the other and not following specified positions.

It looks like the reason is that my implementation uses default JDK interface based proxies, and my custom filters represent the same proxy around Filter interface. So when calling addFilterBefore and addFilterAfter, they are all recognized as the same class and added one after the other which results in incorrect order.

How to overcome this problem?

Is it maybe a problem in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.**FilterComparator** implementation of these methods for adding custom filters?

This is the filter order captured in the debug mode on the incoming request:

[image]

And here is the `Create filter chain` log captured on application start:

```
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@406c0ae9, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@10aa5f84, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@58b6268f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@46c03fe4, org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter@67520476, *.*.*.*.*.Filter1@3e1e994, *.*.*.*.*.Filter2@423c246a, *.*.*.*.*.Filter3@660b4981, *.*.*.*.*.Filter4@e4f3304, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@1efc0d01, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1048c229, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@d814247, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@10c41c8a, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3cd5db14
```

Comment: @dur I see that the order is incorrect when inspecting the details of the filter chain in the debug mode. Also, I get the exception because of wrong execution order. I don't use Spring Boot.

Comment: @dur My filters are in the middle of the chain. I'm pretty sure that the list is ordered when inspecting filter chain that request is going through. `filterToOrder` is maintained during the application startup, correct?

Comment: @dur If I remove `@Bean` annotation then my filters won't be beans and dependency auto wiring will fail. So that's not the option. Although in that case, they will be pure class instances, without proxies, and will be placed correctly in the chain. _Creating filter chain_ log gives the same order as the one on the attached picture (just containing class instances instead of $Proxy364).

Comment: @dur It is the right filter chain, since it's the only one. `FilterChainProxy` does not have `filtersChains` property, there is `additionalFilters` property.

Comment: @dur I don't explicitely use AOP for filters, I'm not sure why are they proxied..

Comment: @dur It looks like it's already a `JdkDynamicAopProxy` in the `configure` method.

Comment: @dur Does `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>` automatically create proxies for my filter beans? I have that configured in one of the modules that my module depends on..

Comment: @dur My filters are not annotated with `@AspectJ`.. So I assume that's not the problem..

Comment: @dur When Spring Security is configured via xml, filter beans are also proxies, but they are placed correctly. So the only conclusion is that Java configuration and methods for adding filter into chain is wrong.

Comment: That's very unlikely, because Java configuration exists some years and no one had the same problem yet. If you can give a MCVE, I can try it in my IDE.